# How to correctly invalidate cache on production for Symfony2 application?

Tags: caching, reload, symfony

I changed the configuration of the application and deployed the new code to production server. Since the application does not parse the configuration files and use precompiled classes I needed to update the cache files.

There is `app/console cache:warmup` and `app/console cache:clear` commands. But the cache wasn't updated after invoking these commands, so I had to delete the app/cache folder manually.

Manual deletion is very dangerous operation because it's not atomic so I can remove part of cache during request and this may lead to fatal error.

How should I reload cache?

Comment: What's so bad about manual deletion?

Comment: If you haven't highload, there is nothing bad with manual deletion. Only permissions for cache and log folders can become invalid.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You missed `env` parameter: `app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: Thanks! Accept your answer with one fix: app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug

Comment: Since 2.1 app/console when no `--env` flag was provided it would default to either `getenv('SYMFONY_ENV')` or `dev`. Also if `--env=prod` was supplied it would force `--no-debug` Prior to 2.1 `--no-debug` needed to be passed explicitly `$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(array('--no-debug', '')) && $env !== 'prod';`  https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/console

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can try 
`app/console cache:clear --no-warmup`

Comment: Thanks, but I have doubt that for highload it's not a good idea to kill the cache. I only need graceful reload for configuration.

Comment: i believe u can follow that up with `app/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

To clear the cache and instantly access the data my fix is

```
sudo app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup --no-debug
```

using this command turns off debug, and doesn't have a warmup time before the data is accessible again

Comment: keep in mind that the `--no-warmup` flag prevents a new environment based cache from being generated after `cache:clear` completes. The delay (cache generation) will occur when the application is run for the first time instead.